# Invalidate canvas part

Tags: android, animation, android-canvas, android-custom-view

I need to create a custom view with animation. I extend View class and override onDraw. This custom view has some method, which when called must redraw with animation canvas(inside onDraw) part. I make the animation via ValueAnimator, inside onAnimationUpdate where I calculate the animation offset and call invalidate(). It works ok, but I must redraw the whole view, the animated part and the rest. I try use

```
invalidate (int l, int t, int r, int b)
```

but in this case the animation does not work. onDraw called only twice.

1. Is it possible to redraw only the canvas part, or must I redraw everything every time?
2. Is it good practice to use ValueAnimator for canvas animation?

Answer (score 1):

Yep, basically you can redraw just a part of the view using the method that you are describing. However, if you are animating using a ValueAnimator, the overhead of redrawing the whole view will be negligible and you will avoid problems in your animations related to "dirty" parts of the view not getting redrawn.

simply call invalidate without arguments.

P.S.: If it gives you some peace of mind, just open the profiling tools and watch them when the animation is run. In normal circumstances you won't even be able to see a reaction.